# Creating check typemap except in destructor

Tags: python, c++, swig

I am using SWIG to create a Python interface to allow plugins for my C++ program.

I have some classes that could look like this:

```
class TStdFunc
{
public:
  void SetColor(unsigned);
  unsigned GetColor() const;
  bool IsValid() const;  
};
```

An object can be deleted by the user. This actually just moves it to an undo stack so the user can undo the operation. However when an object has been "deleted" I don't want a plugin to change it.

I have therefore created a typemap like this:

```
%typemap(check) TStdFunc*
{
  if(!$1->IsValid())
      SWIG_exception_fail(SWIG_RuntimeError, "Element is not valid");
}
```

This works great. If a plugin has stored a reference to the object and tries to call SetColor() or GetColor() after the object has been "deleted" I get an exception.

However the check is also added to the function _wrap_delete_TStdFunc created by SWIG. So when the object is destroyed from Python, I also get an exception. So how do I get a check in all functions except the delete function? Can I disable the typemap for the delete function?

PS. This is of course a simplified explanation. The objects are actually wrapped with boost::shared_ptr, but I don't think that matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution by accident. Adding this after the class definition will remove the check from the destructor while keeping it in all other functions.

```
%extend TStdFunc 
{
  %typemap(check) TStdFunc* ""
}
```

I assume this works because %extend reopens the class definition and the destructor code is generated when the definition of the class is finished.

Answer (score 0):

I've just run into a similar problem. The `%extend` trick didn't work in my case, so I resorted to checking the name of the function in the typemap, like this:

```
%typemap(check) TStdFunc* %{
    if (strcmp("$symname", "delete_TStdFunc"))
        if(!$1->IsValid())
            SWIG_exception_fail(SWIG_RuntimeError, "Element is not valid");
%};
```